# Can we use interpolation function of different order to represent different degrees of freedom in a FEM element?

Tags: finite-element

Consider a line element in FEM. Let each node have 3 DOF. They are x and y translation DOF and temperature. Can we use interpolation functions of different orders for the translation DOFs and Temperature, like say, first-order interpolation function for translation DOF and second-order interpolation for temperature?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can. You end up with something that is often called "mixed finite elements" if, for example, you are considering a formulation that involves velocities and pressures.

Comment: Is it possible to have interpolation functions of a different order for the different components of velocity?

Comment: I suspect you could, but that seems strange to me. Why would you do that? I don't know anyone who has done that and can think of many reasons not to.